# Detect picture box Edges C#

Tags: c#, picturebox

I'm creating a simple bouncing ball application that uses a timer to bounce the ball of the sides of a picture box, the trouble i'm having with this is that it bounces fine off the bottom and right side of the picture box but doesn't bounce off the top or left side and i'm not sure why, the ball size is 30 if you wanted to know

The code for it is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace Ball
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int x = 200, y = 50;        // start position of ball
        int xmove = 10, ymove = 10; // amount of movement for each tick

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void pbxDisplay_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;      // get a graphics object

              // draw a red ball, size 30, at x, y position
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, x, y, 30, 30);
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            x += xmove;             // add 10 to x and y positions
            y += ymove;       
            if(y + 30 >= pbxDisplay.Height)
            {
                ymove = -ymove;
            }
            if (x + 30 >= pbxDisplay.Width)
            {
                xmove = -xmove;
            }
            if (x - 30 >= pbxDisplay.Width)
            {
                xmove = -xmove;
            }
            if (y - 30 >= pbxDisplay.Height)
            {
                ymove = -ymove;
            }
            Refresh();              // refresh the`screen .. calling Paint() again

        }

        private void btnQuit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }


        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled= false;
        }

    }
}
```

If anyone can see what my problem is then please let me know, thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your method for edge recognition is wrong. Top left corner point got coordinates **[0,0]**. So you should check left and top against zero. Not Width and Height.

So your code should look like:

```
  private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            x += xmove;             // add 10 to x and y positions
            y += ymove;       
            if(y + 30 >= pbxDisplay.Height)
            {
                ymove = -ymove;
            }
            if (x + 30 >= pbxDisplay.Width)
            {
                xmove = -xmove;
            }
            if (x - 30 <= 0)
            {
                xmove = -xmove;
            }
            if (y - 30 <= 0)
            {
                ymove = -ymove;
            }
            Refresh();              // refresh the`screen .. calling Paint() again

        }
```